# Plotting python dates with matplotlib: x labels shift to the right

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

When I plot dates using Matplotlib X labels shift to the right. It happens only if there are more than 10-15 entries. I think the problem is with how I handle python dates but cannot figure out what exactly is wrong with my code. I will really appreciate your help.

I get a list of dates in this format:

```
mydates = [datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 17, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 4, 8, 0), etc.]
```

My code:

```
x = mydates
x = date2num(x)
y = female_values
z = male_values

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4.5))
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 10})
ax = plt.subplot(111)
width = 0.2
opacity = 0.5
ax.bar(x, y, width=width, color='orange', align='center', alpha=opacity)
ax.bar(x+width, z, width=width, color='green', align='center', alpha=opacity)
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m'))
plt.xticks(x+(width/2), rotation=60)
plt.legend(['Female', 'Male'], loc='upper left')
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
plt.savefig('myapp/static/charts/'+timestr+'.png')
```

The plot:

[image: X labels shift to the right]

More examples (14 days):

[image]

15 days:

[image]

Comment: did u try setting the number of xticks using set_ticks?

Comment: No, I didn't. Should it be something like `ax.set_xticks(range(len(mydates)))`?

Comment: Yes please try it.

Comment: All labels got squashed to the right when I added this line.

Comment: To me the plot looks good. If this is still an issue, please add more details about in how far the plot does not meet your expectations.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Sorry for the delay, I was away. If you look at where the first date is plotted, you will see a gap between 0 and 01/12. I want to get rid of this gap. Tried so many things but none worked.

Comment: If this issue only occurs with more than 10 to 15 entries, would you mind adding those 15 dates to the question, as to provide a  true [mcve] of the issue?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added two more graphs where you can see how the gap starts appearing. As I add more dates it grows bigger and bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem only occurs in matplotlib versions prior to 2.0.

Appart from updating matplotlib, a solution is to set the margins manually:

```
plt.margins(x=0.04)
```

which means that there should be a space of 4% of the axis size left and right to the data. You can of course try other values.

Comment: Finally! Thank you so much. Works beautifully now.